# SSAS: dynamic filtering of date dimension member

Tags: sql-server, filtering, ssas, mdx

I have database and SSAS with me.

### In DB:

1) fact table `factSales`:

```
+-----------------+----------+
| ColumnName      | Datatype |
+-----------------+----------+
|    JoinDate     |   date   |
| TransactionDate |   date   |
|       Amt       |   money  |
|   CustomerId    |    int   |
|    .......                 |
|    .......                 |
+-----------------+----------+
```

2) time dimension table `dimDate`

```
+-----------------+----------+
|   ColumnName    | Datatype |
+-----------------+----------+
|      Date       |   date   |
|   MonthNumber   |   date   |
|       Year      |    int   |
|       Week      |    int   |
|    .......                 |
|    .......                 |
+-----------------+----------+
```

### In SSAS:

- Measure group `factSales` (with measures: TotalAmt, Sales Count, Customer Distinct Count)
- dimension `JoinDate` (based on `dimDate`)
- dimension `TransactionDate` (based on `dimDate`)

I need to add a functionality to achieve:

For example, a user chooses `TransactionDate` from `2015-01-01` to `2015-02-01`.
I need to add:

1. A new calculate member **BaseCustomersAmt**, which shows only sales made within [`2015-01-01` -- `2015-02-01`] period by customers where `JoinDate` is less than [`2015-01-01`] i.e. 1 year
2. A new calculate member **NewCustomersAmt**, which shows only sales made within [`2015-01-01` -- `2015-02-01`] period by customers where `JoinDate` is greater than or equal to [`2015-01-01`] i.e. 1 year

So, the idea is that I need to split the total sales (**`TotalAmt`**) by two groups -

> **first group** is those who joined more than 1 year ago from chosen period,
>   **second group** the rest - who joined on or after a date which is 1 year ago from a chosen period.

Of course, the user can create two separate reports and use different ranges of Join Date, but the requirement is to do it in one report and do it automatically.

Is it possible to achieve? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> For example, user chooses Transaction Date from 2015-01-01 to 2015-02-01.

I'm going to assume it's at the Date Level and will calculate for Each date. Since i don't know if you have a Time Hierarchy with year-date relationship i'll just use `LAG(365)` to go 1 year back. Otherwise you can use `PARALLELPERIOD`

```
CREATE MEMBER [Measures].[BaseCustomersAmt]
AS
AGGREGATE(
    {
       NULL
       :LINKMEMBER([TransactionDate].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,[JoinDate].[DATE]).LAG(365)
    }
    ,[Measures].[Sales]
),VISIBLE=1;


CREATE MEMBER [Measures].[NewCustomersAmt]
AS
AGGREGATE(
    {
        LINKMEMBER([TransactionDate].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,[JoinDate].[DATE]).LAG(365)
       :LINKMEMBER([TransactionDate].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,[JoinDate].[DATE])
    }
    ,[Measures].[Sales]
),VISIBLE=1;
```

EDIT:

Let's assume you have a Year-Month-Date Hierarchy.

```
CREATE MEMBER [Measures].[NewCustomersAmt]
AS
AGGREGATE(
    {
        ParallelPeriod(
            [JoinDate].[YearMonthDate].[Year]
            ,1
            ,LINKMEMBER([TransactionDate].[YearMonthDate].CURRENTMEMBER,[JoinDate].[YearMonthDate])
        )
       :LINKMEMBER([TransactionDate].[YearMonthDate].CURRENTMEMBER,[JoinDate].[YearMonthDate])
    }
    ,[Measures].[Sales]
),VISIBLE=1;
```

For a Dynamic Lag... i guess it gets more tricky... But you can try to LAG on your baseDayDimension. Don't know if will work.

```
.LAG(
    iif([baseDayDimension].[Day].CURRENTMEMBER IS[baseDayDimension].[Day].[All]
       ,365
       ,[baseDayDimension].[Day].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE
     )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, mxix! It works fine if the user chooses the Date Level (they use Excel and they can drag and use any attribute in the Date dimension). What if they choose Month, or Year, or quarter? How to make that calculation working for any time member in the time hierarchy? And can I make LAG(365) dynamic, e.g. it will use the value of some other dimension, for example, dimBaseDays which has the values: 7, 30, 365 (default), so this Base/New Amount can be calculated for different definitions of Base/New customers? Sorry for asking so many questions in one comment.

Comment: If you have a Hierarchy with Year-Month-Date you can use it directly instead of [Date], but you will have to use Parallel period ate the [Year] level. To make the value you go back Dynamic ofc you can use another Dimension with CURRENTMEMBER of that Dimension Attribute. MEMBER_VALUE propably.

Comment: Ok, got it. It works with Parallel period. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm... ParallelPeriod works with '[JoinDate].[YearMonthDate].[Year]', but if I use Month, it works only when I show months on rows. If I show years, it does not work. Also it's empty value for totals... even for [Year]. Is there a way to have a query which works for any possible choices of members in Date hierarchy?

Comment: ParallelPeriod as i provided moves you one year back. No matter what level you are in. If it doesn't, your time dimension may not be properly configured.

Comment: As I said, 'one year back' works fine, the problem now is with 'one month back' - it works only for 'months on rows', not quarters or years... I thought the same about bad design of time dimension, but I tried it for AdventureWorks and it does not work as well :(

Comment: Please start a new question with examples of what you are trying. Include the code that is not working.